# Bootstrap 14 columns with a horizontal slider/scrollbar

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have **14 columns in a row**, but bootstrap allows only 12, rest 2 columns are coming down. I want all 14 columns in one row **with a horizontal slider or scroll**.

I searched for solutions online but they aren't working in my scenario. So finally landed here for a brainstorming.

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">3</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">4</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">5</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">6</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">7</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">8</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">9</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">10</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">11</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">12</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">13</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">14</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) Don't tag your question with 2 different versions of Bootstrap. Which one are you using? 2) How about you don't use `.row` and `.col-x`? Have you tried anything? 3) Bootstrap grid system can be [customized](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#customizing-the-grid).

Comment: I am using bootstrap 5. I will try the customization you shared and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [auto-layout columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns) to have more than 12 columns, and apply overflow-x-scroll and flex-nowrap to the row to be able to scroll horizontally through the columns.

To keep the columns from shrinking to fit, you can give them a custom class with no flex and a fixed width to fit your content.

```css
.col-14 {
    flex: none;
    width: 120px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="../../index.html">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="./products.html">Products</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="./about.html">About us</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<main class="container">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap text-center overflow-x-scroll">
        <div class="col-14">1</div>
        <div class="col-14">2</div>
        <div class="col-14">3</div>
        <div class="col-14">4</div>
        <div class="col-14">5</div>
        <div class="col-14">6</div>
        <div class="col-14">7</div>
        <div class="col-14">8</div>
        <div class="col-14">9</div>
        <div class="col-14">10</div>
        <div class="col-14">11</div>
        <div class="col-14">12</div>
        <div class="col-14">13</div>
        <div class="col-14">14</div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but It's not working in bootstrap 5. Horizontal bar is coming for the whole page, not the grid. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “not working in Bootstrap 5” as the code snippet I provided is running Bootstrap 5.3.0. In the code snippet, the horizontal scroll bar is the full width of the container div (the main tag). I’m not sure what you mean by “the grid.”